# Cordova how to remove "Push notification" on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, feedback

I submitted my application using Apache Cordova to Apple Store and I got a warning from apple that "Missing Push Notification Entitlement".

But it seems that I've never used "Push Notification" in my application. How can I remove it from my application? Is it default in Apache Cordova?

Comment: please list the plugins you are using and cordova version

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**HOW TO DO THIS FOR CORDOVA APPS 'PROPERLY':**

I also had this problem. The solution proposed by @michaelb worked but I was frustrated enough seeing that the whole thing was wrapped in conditional compilation (ie `#ifndef DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS`) that I decided to learn how to add a 'Preprocessor Macro', which basically tells XCode to compile you app with this bit of code left out.

This is how the you can define the `DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS` precompilation symbol graphically via the UI (note that this the way its done in XCode 6.1):

[image]

Hope this helps other people out there in same situation.

Answer (score 5):

In AppDelegate.m remove didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken and didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError. Working on PhoneGap 3.5

Answer (score 5):

Following the advise above and in other places, this is what I did in Cordova 5.0.0

As result the warning disappeared and I haven't noticed any problem with the App.

1. Open platforms/ios/InfoganGardenAdmin/Classes/AppDelegate.m
2. Comment out line 116 to 137

example:

```
/* - Removed to disable push notification and Apple warning message
#ifndef DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS

    - (void)                                 application:(UIApplication*)application
        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
    {
        // re-post ( broadcast )
        NSString* token = [[[[deviceToken description]
            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""]
            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CDVRemoteNotification object:token];
    }

    - (void)                                 application:(UIApplication*)application
        didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
    {
        // re-post ( broadcast )
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CDVRemoteNotificationError object:error];
    }
#endif
*/
```

Comment: Did you make sure `DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS` was in fact defined ? It should have the same effect as what you're doing... weirdly, it is defined in my builds, but I still get the warnings.

Comment: I tried to set this flag but it didn't worked. I am not an expert in this so I might did it badly

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely an issue with the version you are using, PhoneGap 3.5 has that same issue (PhoneGap is built on Cordova), you can view the discussion thread [here](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/pgb_3_5_missing_push_notification_entitlement)

The current solution seems to be *"use an older version"*

Answer (score -1):

The email is pretty vague and can be taken multiple ways plus if you are a new developer you may not have known about the wait time for Apple Store app reviews. See [AppReviewTimes](http://appreviewtimes.com/).

To Clarify: Its just a warning and you can ignore it if you don't use push notifications.

Don't try to fix what ain't broke. Plus all the solutions I could find didn't work.