# Unnecessary warning Missing Push Notification Entitlement

Tags: ios, push-notification, xcode8, code-signing-entitlements

I am not using any push notification service for app. and My AppID in member centre also don't have tick on push service. 
when I try to submit app to appstore, every time I got below warning

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register
>   with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's
>   entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your
>   app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is
>   enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit
>   after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that
>   includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. Xcode 8 does not
>   automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning
>   profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this
>   entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's
>   Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your
>   entitlements file.

any solution?

Comment: look into this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945557/missing-push-notification-entitlement-warning
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807129/missing-push-notification-entitlement

Comment: @Gagan_iOS my problem is different, my app don't have push notification service still i got warning.

Comment: Did you find an answer?