# Missing Push Notification Entitlement, even with aps-environment entitlement set. iOS and Testflight

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Good morning!

I am working on getting my app to receive push notifications from Firebase cloud messaging. when I add my build to testflight, I get a warning email with the error code: **ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement**, I am allowing xcode to manage my profile, which has the aps-environment entitlement and the capability for push notifications, and a development signing certificate, as you can see in this screenshot from xcode:

[image]

Luckily, this is just a warning, so I can still push this build to my testflight testers, but they do not receive push notifications. I can confirm that firebase cloud messaging is generating the device messaging token, and it is storing in my firebase database just fine, so I assume this is not the issue.

I have also confirmed that I have a Production Apple Push notification SSL cert assigned to this bundle ID, as shown here:
[image]

[image]

After I took this screenshot, I also tried adding a development SSL cert, but the problem persists.

I have found a number of other posts on apple dev forums and here on Stack exchange, but most are fron over 4 years ago and no longer appear relevant. Example: [Missing Push Notification Entitlement warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945557/missing-push-notification-entitlement-warning)

What am I missing? Thank you for your time and help in advance!

**UPDATE**

I have now also attempted the to fix this by using a provisioning profile I set up, rather than allowing xcode to manage it for me. It is an "App Store Distribution" Profile.[image]

[image]

Same issue, getting the same email error, and any installed applications do not receive push notifications. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After a multi - hour debug session with a friend of mine that is better versed in Apple processes than I am, we managed to figure out the issue. Everything was set up correctly... all my certs were in line, all of the profiles and Bundle IDs matched, everything looked good. The issue was for some reason, xcode was displaying all of my certs from appstoreconnect and developer.apple.com, but it was not including a local entitlements file with the binary that ultimately got uploaded to app store connect, which drew the error, and ultimately prevented push notifications from working. The fix was simple... just click "+ capability" next to "all" in signing and capabilities, search for and add push notifications, and bingo! This adds the proper entitlements to my binary, which then look for the certs in app store connect. This now uploads without the error message and push notifications on any installs from this new build starting working immediately. I hope this helps someone, someday! Apple, please make this more straightforward, or don't let xcode lie about its certs!

Comment: just click "+ capability" next to "all" in signing and capabilities, search for and add push notifications <------- THIS

Comment: Hi I have a similar problem. I have the entitlements file but I think are not being shipped with the IPA