# Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications

I am working on a cordova app that does NOT use push notifications. I uploaded that app to the app store and received the following information:

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement.

Now, I would like to disable the push notification service API, but how would I do that?

I found that [I could add the `DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS` compiler flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945557/missing-push-notification-entitlement-warning) to my compiler flags, but I did not find a working manual on how/where to change them. Perhaps someone knows an easy way to change it?

Otherwise, I did find a [script for a hook](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/8dcc9dd626c523e6e217dd7e8ce43d0af849fa3a/bin/templates/project/__PROJECT_NAME__/Classes/AppDelegate.m#L116), but after I added that script to the before_prepare hooks, I get the error `env: node\r: no such file or directory`. I changed all the EOLs to UNIX style in that hook script, but the error remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your app code **does not contain** any push notification related code. Like the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

**EDIT:**
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30595865/598812), you have to edit your Objective-C code. It's an issue with cordova.

Comment: But if I remove code from the iOS app, and then rebuild it from the cordova app (`cordova build ios`), the removed code will be re-inserted, right?

Comment: Then remove any push related feature from cordova's code.

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30595865/598812 you have to edit your Objective-C code. It's an issue with cordova.